# How to get GCP sign-up credits?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have received the sign-up verification email from gcp saying that: "Verify your business email address today to receive up to $700 USD in additional credit to use during your free trial.". But there are no instructions on where/how-to to do it. Any idea anyone?

I have tried looking into billing and profile details. My business email is already in there --I had supplied that while signing up.

Comment: Post the redacted email that you received. Each one that I have seen has details on what to do next. Perhaps a scam email?